# Groupby Pandas , calculate multiple columns based on date difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe shown below:

```
CID RefID   Date        Group   MID 
100     1   1/01/2021       A                       
100     2   3/01/2021       A                       
100     3   4/01/2021       A   101             
100     4   15/01/2021      A                           
100     5   18/01/2021      A                   
200     6   3/03/2021       B                       
200     7   4/04/2021       B                       
200     8   9/04/2021       B   102             
200     9   25/04/2021      B                       
300     10  26/04/2021      C                       
300     11  27/05/2021      C           
300     12  28/05/2021      C   103
```

I want to create three columns:

days_diff:

1. This has to be created in a way that if the difference b/w the first Date and corresponding rows is greater than 30 belonging to the same CID then assign 'NAT' or 0 to the next row (reset) and then subtract the date with this row for the following values
2. If MIDis not null and belong to same CID group assign 'NAT' or 0 to the next row (reset)
   and then subtract the date with this row for the following values

Otherwise just fetch the date difference b/w the first row belonging to the same CID for the corresponding rows

A:
This depends on the days_diff column , this column is like a counter it will only change/increment  when there's another NAT occurrence for the same CID and reset itself for every CID.

B: This column depends on the column A , if the value in A remains same it won't change otherwise increments

It's a bit complicated to explain please refer to the output below for reference. I have used `.groupby()` `.diff()` and  `.shift()` methods to create multiple dummy columns in order to calculate this and still working on it, please let me know the best way to go about this, thanks

My expected output :

```
CID RefID   Date        Group   MID     days_diff       A   B
100     1   1/01/2021       A           NAT             1   1
100     2   3/01/2021       A           2 days          1   1
100     3   4/01/2021       A   101     3 days          1   1
100     4   15/01/2021      A           NAT             2   4
100     5   18/01/2021      A           3 days          2   4
200     6   3/03/2021       B           NAT             1   6
200     7   4/04/2021       B           NAT             2   7
200     8   9/04/2021       B   102     5 days          2   7
200     9   25/04/2021      B           NAT             3   9
300     10  26/04/2021      C           NAT             1   10
300     11  27/05/2021      C           NAT             2   11
300     12  28/05/2021      C   103     1 day           2   11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def days_diff(sdf):
    result = pd.DataFrame(
        {"days_diff": pd.NaT, "A": None}, index=sdf.index
    )
    start = sdf.at[sdf.index[0], "Date"]
    for index, day, next_MID_is_na in zip(
        sdf.index[1:], sdf.Date[1:], sdf.MID.shift(1).isna()[1:]
    ):
        diff = (day - start).days
        if diff <= 30 and next_MID_is_na:
            result.at[index, "days_diff"] = diff
        else:
            start = day
    result.A = result.days_diff.isna().cumsum()
    return result

df[["days_diff", "A"]] = df[["CID", "Date", "MID"]].groupby("CID").apply(days_diff)
df["B"] = df.RefID.where(df.A != df.A.shift(1)).ffill()
```

Result for `df` created by

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
'''
CID RefID   Date        Group   MID 
100     1   1/01/2021       A                       
100     2   3/01/2021       A                       
100     3   4/01/2021       A   101             
100     4   15/01/2021      A                           
100     5   18/01/2021      A                   
200     6   3/03/2021       B                       
200     7   4/04/2021       B                       
200     8   9/04/2021       B   102             
200     9   25/04/2021      B                       
300     10  26/04/2021      C                       
300     11  27/05/2021      C           
300     12  28/05/2021      C   103
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

is

```
    CID  RefID       Date Group    MID days_diff  A     B
0   100      1 2021-01-01     A    NaN       NaT  1   1.0
1   100      2 2021-01-03     A    NaN         2  1   1.0
2   100      3 2021-01-04     A  101.0         3  1   1.0
3   100      4 2021-01-15     A    NaN       NaT  2   4.0
4   100      5 2021-01-18     A    NaN         3  2   4.0
5   200      6 2021-03-03     B    NaN       NaT  1   6.0
6   200      7 2021-04-04     B    NaN       NaT  2   7.0
7   200      8 2021-04-09     B  102.0         5  2   7.0
8   200      9 2021-04-25     B    NaN       NaT  3   9.0
9   300     10 2021-04-26     C    NaN       NaT  1  10.0
10  300     11 2021-05-27     C    NaN       NaT  2  11.0
11  300     12 2021-05-28     C  103.0         1  2  11.0
```

---

A few explanations:

- The function `days_diff` produces a dataframe with the two columns `days_diff` and `A`. It is applied to the grouped by column `CID` sub-dataframes of `df`.
- First step: Initializing the result dataframe `result` (column `days_diff` filled with `NaT`, column `A` with `None`), and setting the starting value `start` for the day differences to the first day in the group.
- Afterwards essentially looping over the sub-dataframe *after* the first index, thereby grabbing the index, the value in column `Date`, and a boolean value `next_MID_is_na` that signifies if the value of the `MID` column in the *next* row ist `NaN` (via `.shift(1).isna()`).
- In every step of the loop:

  1. Calculation of the difference of the current day to the start day.
  2. Checking the rules for the `days_diff` column:

     - If difference of current and start day <= 30 days *and* `NaN` in next `MID`-row -> day-difference.
     - Otherwise -> reset of `start` to the current day.
- After finishing column `days_diff` calculation of column `A`: `result.days_diff.isna()` is `True` (`== 1`) when `days_diff` is `NaN`, `False` (`== 0`) otherwise. Therefore the cummulative sum (`.cumsum()`) gives the required result.
- After the `groupby-apply` to produce the columns `days_diff` and `A` finally the calculation of column `B`: Selection of `RefID`-values where the values `A` change (via `.where(df.A != df.A.shift(1))`), and then *forward* filling the remaining `NaN`s.

Comment: First of all excellent job mate , can't thank you enough @Timus and for ```refid == 5``` the ```days_diff``` is calculated as ```(2021-02-18) - (2021-01-15) = 3```  , since the previous value is 'NAT' of the same column belonging to the same CID

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions, I could have done a better job explaining the logic but I find it very difficult to explain, fyi upvoted

Comment: @Ash I'm still confused: The difference between `2021-02-18` and `2021-01-15` is 34 days, and therefore `> 30`?

Comment: I am so sorry it supposed to be ```(2021-01-18) - (2021-01-15) = 3``` , I made a mistake while creating a dummy dataset , I apologise. I have updated my question

Comment: @Ash Okay, makes sense now! I've updated the results with the new input.

Comment: Legend, and answer accepted, may you also update answer with  how you created your sample dataset for the same

Comment: @Ash Sure, see the last edit.

Comment: Thanks @Timus can't thank you enough seriously, now what I will do is to try to break down the code and try to understand what you've done, again thank heaps mate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238099/discussion-between-ash-and-timus).

Comment: @Ash Sorry, I'm at work and the chat site is blocked :(

Comment: No worries mate totally understand , only if you have time would you let me know how did you construct your solution, so that I will be able to do something like this in future,. Otherwise all good  :)

Comment: @Ash I have added a few explanations. I hope they are clear enough and helpful.