# Create a new column using the previous rows , pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below

```
CID RefID   Date        Group   MID 
100     1   1/01/2021       A   101                     
100     2   3/01/2021       A   nan                   
100     3   4/01/2021       A   nan            
100     4   15/01/2021      A   nan
```

I want to transform the 'MID' column in a way that :
MID + RefID = MID  and so on for all the other values. I have used `.shift()` method but didn't get the desired output

Expected output:

```
CID RefID   Date        Group   MID 
100     1   1/01/2021       A   101                     
100     2   3/01/2021       A   102                   
100     3   4/01/2021       A   104            
100     4   15/01/2021      A   107
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cumsum` and `shift`:

```
>>> df['MID'] = df['MID'].ffill() + df['RefID'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
>>> df
   CID  RefID        Date Group    MID
0  100      1   1/01/2021     A  101.0
1  100      2   3/01/2021     A  102.0
2  100      3   4/01/2021     A  104.0
3  100      4  15/01/2021     A  107.0
>>>
```

Comment: Legend strikes back. Upvote deserved and accepted your answer. @U12-Forward May you help me with this one as well ,  I am really struggling with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548953/groupby-pandas-calculate-multiple-columns-based-on-date-difference